# leftmost path in planar embedding

Tags: algorithm, planar-graph

I have a directed planar Graph. Therefore I can make a planar embedding. 
I have to nodes s and t and I would like to find the leftmost path between s and t according to a specific embedding.

Left is defined as David described in the comment. That means  "Left" is defined with respect to an infinite face and a clockwise/counterclockwise convention. A path p is left of a path q with the same endpoints if the cycle p*rev(q) is at least as counterclockwise with respect to winding the infinite face as any other face.

How is that possible? 
I have no idea how to tell my programm if a path is left of another one. I read a few paper, but they didn't explain how to implement that.
Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Might belong to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do yo mean by "left"?

Comment: @iavr "Left" is defined with respect to an infinite face and a clockwise/counterclockwise convention. A path p is left of a path q with the same endpoints if the cycle p\*rev(q) is at least as counterclockwise with respect to winding the infinite face as any other face.

Comment: Ping me if this question gets reopened (and as a purely strategic thing, don't tag language-agnostic questions with the programming language that you happen to be using, because the new audience that you get is more likely to put it on hold).

Comment: @user3399670 Can you point to the papers you've read?

Comment: Here's a link to my advisor's draft book on planar graph algorithms: http://planarity.org/ , which should have all of the relevant definitions.

Comment: http://cs.brown.edu/~pnk/publications/st-flow.pdf

Comment: @user3399670 Ah. Some combination of Jeff Erickson and Philip and me recently proved that you don't actually need to initialize leftmost.

Comment: H. Ripphausen-Lipa, D. Wagner, and K. Weihe. The
vertex-disjoint menger problem in planar graphs. In
4th SODA, pages 112–119, 1993.

Comment: There's an implementation of Borradaile--Klein linked from this page: http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/code/

Comment: Answer that I can't post due to robo-reviewers: http://pastebin.com/xMqhXsqm

Comment: Thank you very much, David =) 
Acutally I like to implement the max flow algorithm by Borradaile and Klein with different Dynamic Trees.
Do you mean with not initializing leftmost that the graph can have positive cycles? Does that means that the maxflow algorithm can be used on every possible planar graph without restriction?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat could you please point to the paper where Erickson, Klein and you proved that you don't actually need to initialize leftmost?

Comment: [Linear-time algorithms for max flow and multiple-source shortest paths in unit-weight planar graphs](http://www.davideisenstat.com/cv/EisenstatK13.pdf) (That part of the correctness proof doesn't require unit weights.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user3568609 notes, the planar embedding is on a sphere, with no
natural definition of left and right. You need to choose an infinite
face first; for flow algorithms (I assume that this is what you’re
implementing), it’s often convenient to choose a face incident to s or
t. Let’s suppose that the infinite face is incident to t. The
counterclockwise order of half-edges into t now has a natural gap where
the infinite face is.

```
.4  3| /2  .
 \___|/___/
     t  1

(infinite face)
```

Visit the half-edges in counterclockwise order, 1 to 4 in the example.
This is a depth-first traversal, so we fully explore 1’s connections
before 2’s, etc. When you arrive at another vertex v from another vertex
u then the picture looks like this

```
|3   |2
 \___|___/1
     v
     |
     u
```

Once again I’ve labeled the proper traversal order.

Answer (score 0):

A simple planar graph has no notion of left and right, it can be mirrored and rotated still being planar.
You have to embed some kind of direction into the graph.

If the maximum out degree of a node is 2 you can label the left edge.
To find the left most path you can make a depth first search starting from s.
When you reach a new node always take the left edge first.
The algorithm should terminate when t is reached, leaving you the the left most path.

In the case of arbitrary maximum out degree you can label the edges with increasing numbers from left to right.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know what the left edge is. For example I have a list of out edges of a vertex v. How do I know which one is the leftmost one?

Comment: If "left" is defined as given by David Eisenstat in his comment, then this depends on both endpoints `s` and `t`, so edges cannot be really labeled.

Comment: @user3399670 It's context-dependent. I was trying to post an answer before the hold came, of which the tl;dr is choose the infinite face incident to t; then rightmost with respect to t is defined. Do a DFS traversal; then rightmost is defined with respect to the incoming half-edge of the current traversal location. (Leftmost from s <=> rightmost from t.)